A movie from the 90s or 2000s, about 2 guys, that everything they could think would simply disappears from existence
Its been soo long so my memories is vague and could be flawed, but I think they were in a house with the windows barricaded and they were on the couch watching the news because they were wanted by the cops or the s.w.a.t for I dunno why.
And then when the cops were close and could hear the sirens, one of them simply think about it or thinking about them to disappears and then everything went silent, they went outside and they vanished.
Then they tried thinking about other things to see if thats how they did it.
Afterward, they were just thinking about stuff that sucked for them so they could live "the perfect life". And then it went to shit when one of them thought about stuff of his friend that annoyed him and his friend did the same out of anger.
It went on to the point they would be the only 2 last remaining on earth. Everything vanished, they were the last 2 in a white background... until they were making themself disappears.
Well thats about it, kinda suck I spoiled everything but yeah.
Thanks for the help.

If my answer is right (which I think it is) please mark it as correct. Thanks.

Nothing (2003), a Canadian film starring David Hewlett pre-Stargate Atlantis.

The film tells the story of two good friends and housemates, Andrew
  (Andrew Miller), an agoraphobic travel agent, and Dave (David
  Hewlett), a loser who works in an office. Dave is fired from his job
  after his girlfriend frames him for embezzlement, Andrew is falsely
  accused of attempted child molestation, and their house is to be
  demolished by day's end. Both of them hide inside the house as police,
  city officials, and outraged neighbors surround it. Dave and Andrew
  open their front door and discover that the entire world beyond their
  house is gone, replaced with a featureless white void.
...
Panic begins to set in again when Andrew realizes that the house is
  completely out of food. Andrew glances around the room, eventually
  stopping and glaring at a noisy clock on the wall; within a few
  seconds it disappears. Andrew drops a stack of overdue bills in front
  of Dave, and within seconds the bills abruptly disappear. Dave puts
  one last theory to test, managing to hate away his need for food.
...
Things become very tense with Dave's departure. Dave attempts to
  engage Andrew in conversation repeatedly, even performing the national
  anthem for his self-created nation (its borders marked by a line of
  his possessions), all to no avail. After several days Dave comes into
  Andrew's house much happier and explains his sudden change of mood: he
  has hated away his anger at Andrew; all Andrew needs to do is hate
  away his anger at Dave and things will be back to normal. Andrew
  refuses, quite content to be angry at Dave. Dave hates away his anger
  several times as Andrew rebuffs and outright insults him, but his
  patience finally wears thin, leading Dave to hate away one of Andrew's
  possessions. Andrew retaliates by hating away one of Dave's
  possessions, and the situation escalates until everything including
  the house is hated away.
Dave walks away, assuming the argument is finished, but falls over
  suddenly as his feet begin to disappear; Andrew is hating them away.
  He turns and retaliates, hating away Andrew's legs, and the situation
  escalates again until all that is left of the two are their
  disembodied heads. Refusing to give up the fight, Andrew and Dave
  manage to turn themselves and (by bouncing) charge at each other,
  headbutting each other repeatedly until they finally stop, exhausted.
  Their anger abated, Dave and Andrew make up, agree to be best friends
  again, and set off to explore the nothingness. As they bounce away
  into the white void they remark how they both had always thought that
  their bodies were somehow holding them back.
In a post-credits scene, an obviously older Dave and Andrew – still
  disembodied heads – are sleeping when they are awakened by a popping
  sound, followed by a loud clamoring of voices and noise. As the unseen
  source of the clamoring gets louder and closer the two scream.

